# Are concurrent queries via same endpoint possible using useLazyQueryHook in Redux Toolkit

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

**The problem:** When doing multiple requests to the same endpoint,  useLazyQueryHook will return a response only with the latest query with status set to 'fulfilled' and response data, while other requests made before are stuck with status 'pending' and without response data.

**Desired functionality**: The lazy query hook does not overwrite the previous returns (if overwrite is the case) but returns data from each query which can be accessed in a useEffect hook f.ex. Is this possibly not the correct approach for this use case when using RTK?

I have the following endpoint within createAPI...

```
  getLoggerCheck: builder.query<any, any>({
        query: ({ loggerId }) => ({
            url: '/scan/check',
            params: {
                logger: loggerId,
            }
        }),
        transformResponse(data: any) {
            console.log(data);   // <---- Correct data for each request is logged out here
            return data;
        }
    })
```

... but when using the generated useLazyGetLoggerCheckQuery hook like so and making approx 5 requests / sec with `runLoggerChecks({loggerId: XXXXX})` only the most recent query is returned with data and status 'fulfilled'.

```
const [runLoggerCheck, loggerCheckResponse] = useLazyGetLoggerCheckQuery();

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(loggerCheckResponse)
}, [loggerCheckResponse]);
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Olafur, did you get the solution?